# Fan-In/Fan-Out - Circuit - Explain why this circuit does not work

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

[image]

Problem: Explain why this circuit does not work for Fan-In=1 and Fan-Out=3 for all logic gates(including the complex logic gate).

Firstly, I would say the Inverter Gate is fine because it does not violate the Fan-Out=3.
But I don't know what the problem is in the case of Fan-In=1.

Secondly, I would say that because x is routed to the 3 inputs of the complex logic that the Fan-In=3 thus it would overload the inverter thus making the gate not work properly.

Am I right?
Hope somebody can give me a lead and or help me.

Comment: Fan-out is the number of *standard load* inputs the output to be characterised is able to drive (watch out for unlike definitions of this standard load). Fan-in is the number of standard inputs the input to be characterised is equivalent to. At a fan-in of 1 for both inverter and *some complex logic gate*, there are four input loads connected to *x*: difficult to drive with an output capable of driving three. If fan-in of the complex gate was .2, there would be just 1.6 standard loads to drive.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Fan-in count.*

Does that help?

Comment: Could it be that the complex logic gate can not handle 3 Inputs because the Fan-In=1?

Comment: How many inputs is 'X' driving?

Comment: X drives 4 inputs. So I would say that I need to add extra gates to make the circuit work?

Comment: Your question doesn't ask how to make it work. It asks why it doesn't. I've answered that. Yes, if the fan-in is too high you will need buffers.