# Why does this circut not work for Fan-In=1 and Fan-Out=3

Tags: logic-gates

[image]

Problem: Explain why this circuit does not work for Fan-In=1 and Fan-Out=3 for all logic gates(including the complex logic gate).

Could someone explain me why this circuit does not work?

I tried it since yesterday but I don't have a clue.
Especially Fan-In/Out confuses me.

sincerely,
Hisoka

Comment: Please give some insight what "some complex logic gate" actually is.

Comment: It is only defined as a "complex logic with multiple inputs".

Comment: You accepted an answer to this exact same question yesterday.

Comment: You asked the [exact same question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341813/fan-in-fan-out-circuit-explain-why-this-circuit-does-not-work) yesterday and accepted my answer. That's usually a sign that you understand the answer and consider it correct. Please don't duplicate the question. Instead un-accept my answer and edit your question to seek clarification on some point.

Answer (score 1):

Using analog ratios of equivalent loads, X sees a load rating of 4 and assuming outputs including X are only rated for a load of 3 units of some bipolar logic family current Fan-in load of 4 > Fan out rating of 3.

Normally each TTL logic family has a fan out of 10, so this is a hypothetical question.

Comment: I assume this would then lead to a overload of the inverter and the complex logic gate(left side)?

Comment: It would make the voltage noise margin less than standard with 4 units of load current due to the source impedance of the driver only rated for 3.  It's not a heat overload problem , rather  adequate voltage noise margin for "1","0".  All logic is simply an analog switched voltage with a series R. so fan out and in are actually equivalent R loads and the R ratio of load to source affects the net voltage against defined limits for safe error free logic levels

Comment: Better than [transistor's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/341815) for not insinuating you could *count fan-in*. I can sum up weighted counts.

Comment: `Normally each TTL logic family has a fan out of 10` erm. Taking a 1970 TI TTL input load of \$I_{IL}\$ -1.6 mA, \$I_{IH}\$ 40 μA as *the* standard, LS had a ("standard/unit load") fan-out of 5. At \$I_{IL}\$ -.4 mA, *in family* fan-out was 20. "standard load" fan-in was .5 (S: in family fan-out 20, standard fan-out 25, fan-in 2.5(! same as H)).